# JavaScript - Apply function call to object with another prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, prototype, ecmascript-2016

The task (actually the problem) I'm facing is the following. I have an array (let’s call it `arr`). The first element of the array is a function and the rest are arguments. For example:

```
arr = [(a, b) => a + b, 5, 7];
```

So, I need to call function `(a, b) => a + b` with arguments `5` and `7`. However, I don't want to use `arr[0](...arr.slice(1))`, instead I want to do it using `Function.prototype.apply` and `Function.prototype.call` (I can also use `Function.prototype.bind` if needed). So basically, I am allowed to access `arr` only once and no other variables may be used. Also, I'm not allowed to modify `arr` or it's properties, or to store any other data somewhere (like as property of some global object, etc). Is that even possible?

#### My attempt

I tried to figure it out, and this is what I came up with (it doesn't work):

```
Function.prototype.apply.call(this, ...arr);
```

However, it throws an error saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on #Global, which is an object and not a function

#### Question

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: What did you think `this` refers to in your example? The following would work: `Function.prototype.call(...arr)`.

Comment: @FelixKling. Sorry, I deleted question by an accident. Well, your example doesn't return `12` as expected, but instead it returns `undefined`.

Comment: Oh, right I got confused.... I don't think it's possible do this without slicing the array one way or the other.

Comment: There is no built-in function that allows you to pass `func, arg1, arg2, ....` as arguments (and have it call `func`). The closest you can get is `func, thisValue, arg1, arg2,...`. But your array doesn't contain a `this` value. Of course you can build a helper function: `function call(f, ...args) { return f(...args);}`. Then you can do `call(...arr)`.

Comment: @user_guest_333 Will the `.length` of `arr` always be the same?

Comment: @guest271314. no.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You can use destructuring to get the elements of `arr` array as variables, then call the function at index `0` with elements at indexes 1-N

```js
let arr = [(a, b) => a + b, 5, 7];
let [fn, a, b] = arr;
console.log(fn(a, b));
```

For any number of elements at indexes 1-N you can use rest element

```js
let arr = [(a, b) => a + b, 5, 7];
let [fn, ...rest] = arr;
console.log(fn.apply(null, rest));
```

Alternatively, using `Function`, template literal to convert array to string, `.replace()` with `RegExp`  `/\s/g` with `.replace()` to remove space characters, `.match()` with `RegExp` `/(\(.*\)=>[^,]+(?=,))|[^,]{1}[^\1]+/g` to capture arrow function, negate first comma of characters that are not arrow function and arrow function captured at first group, we can reference `arr` once and not create additional variables save for immediately invoked arrow function parameters

```js
let arr = [(a, b) => a + b, 5, 7];

console.log(
  (([a, b]) => new Function(`return (${a})(${b.split(/,/)})`)())
  (`${arr}`.replace(/\s/g, "").match(/(\(.*\)=>[^,]+(?=,))|[^,]{1}[^\1]+/g))
)
```

Comment: I know about destructuring, but this is definitely now what I've asked. But anyway, as other users explained, I'm starting to beliveve that there is not builtin method to do what I want.

Comment: @user_guest_333 What do you mean by "builtin"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I was trying to access identifier `arr` only once and also not to use other identifiers (variables). Slicing array requires at least two accessing of `arr`.

Comment: @user_guest_333 The code at Answer accesses `arr` only once. By "not use other identifiers" do you mean to not assign a variable identifier to elements of `arr`? Are you trying to do `arr.shift().apply(null, arr)`?

Comment: After you've done all this destructuring and rest elements, why don't you just do `fn(...rest)`?

Answer (score 2):

> instead I want to do it using Function.prototype.apply and Function.prototype.call. Is that even possible?

Sure, but we have to repeat `arr`:

```
arr[0].call(...arr)
```

Live Example:

```js
const arr = [(a, b) => a + b, 5, 7];
console.log(arr[0].call(...arr));
```

That wouldn't work if the function required a specific `this`, but your function doesn't, for two reasons, either of which would be sufficient: 1. It's an arrow function, so it doesn't care what `this` we call it with, it closes over the one where it was created; and 2. It doesn't use `this` anyway.

**That said**, probably better just to give yourself a helper function that does it instead.

Comment: What if `this` argument is allowed to be `arr` itself? Is that possible without slicing then?

Comment: @user_guest_333: Doh! Of course, because with an arrow function, `thisArg` doesn't get used anyway. But we still have to repeat `arr`. Fixed.

Comment: Essentially, the OP's question is a question of how to do some function "algebra" with `Function.prototype.apply` and `Function.prototype.call`, so this may get the job done, but sort of misses the point.

Comment: @torazaburo: Well, I disagree, esp. in light of the (very surprisingly) accepted answer.